# Motor temperature rise and overload protection

Tags: motor, nec

The NEC section 430.32 A 1 states:

Motors with a marked service factor of 1.15 or greater: 125% 
Motors with a marked temperature rise of 40°C or less: 125% 
All other motors: 115%

I have a question regarding the sentence:

> Motors with a marked temperature rise of 40°C or less: 125%.

If the motor has a rise temperature of 40°C or less, it means that it has not a lot of temperature to increase. For example, if it is a Class A motor with a service factor (SF) of 1.0, operating in an ambient temperature of 30°C, and a hot spot of 5°C, resulting in a temperature rise of 70°C, it exceeds the 40°C limit. According to standard practice, this motor would typically require overload protection set at 1.15 times the Full Load Amps (FLA).

The question arises: Why would a motor with a lower temperature rise have protection set at 1.25 times FLA?

The following image shows the temperature increase according to the class of motors, according to the ambient temperature and according to SF. As you can see, they all have a temperature rise greater than 40°C.

[image]